# Ubuntu takes complete hard disk for installation without considering pre-existing partitions

Tags: installation, 12.10, dual-boot, partitioning

I have recently installed Windows 7 on my laptop with 320 GB HD. Then, I made a partition so now I have 2 primary and 3 logical partitions (all NTFS). I want to install Ubuntu 12.10 so I used ube and Ubuntu 12.10 live. But problem is whenever I try to install Ubuntu from pen drive, it shows that there are no partitions so it wants to partition the whole hard disk.

I searched on web but didn't find suitable a solution. My question is how can I install Ubuntu in this case?

Comment: Can you add the output of `sudo fdisk -l` to your question?

Answer (score 0):

This symptom is most often caused by one of two problems:

- **Leftover RAID data** -- If the disk was used in a RAID setup (which is sometimes the case even on single-disk setups, depending on your firmware settings), it may contain RAID data that will confuse libparted, the partitioning library used by the Ubuntu installer. Typing `sudo dmraid -E -r /dev/sda` will usually correct this problem. Do this *only* if you're *positive* that you're *not* actively using RAID on the disk, though; if Windows is using the RAID setup, this command will cause serious problems!
- **Damaged partition table** -- Even minor damage to a partition table caused libparted to flake out. Most such problems can be fixed by my [FixParts program.](http://www.rodsbooks.com/fixparts/) The Web page describes details of its use. On occasion, problems will need to be corrected in some other way, but more information (like the `fdisk` output that Mitch has requested) is necessary to diagnose the problem.